# Whats the best module or method for A/B testing with Drupal?

Tags: drupal, a-b-testing

I'm looking into rolling our company's static websites into Drupal. I need to ensure that I won't ruin our chances for split testing our designs and layouts. I have found several modules out there, and was wondering if you folks had any advice as to which ones worked the best and why.

Additionally, if you know of any alternative methods, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google website optimizer is free and used by a lot of people I've not tested it with Drupal but here's a link with step by step instructions so I would think you would have no problems http://www.drupalseobook.com/news/google-website-optimizer-with-drupal. (since it's free it's easy enough to test it first). A paid option which I use and highly recommend is Visual Website Optimizer. The cost is minimal and it should work on anything.

Answer (score 1):

We visual website optimizer http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com and there is a drupal module for that too, it's made us convert a good deal better, can't recommend it enough.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is Drupal specific, as I believe your question was project/module based.

We've used [Multivariate](http://drupal.org/project/multivariate) to do a range of multivariate or AB testing.

I know there is a Webform AB test module as well, but the options are somewhat more limited.

While this question was over a year ago and you've no doubt moved on - hopefully someone else can benefit from this answer.

Comment: Is [MultiVariate][1] the name of the module, or is there a different name? I can't seem to find anything out there as a module with that name. Thanks for following up, by the way! We moved away from Drupal for that project, but we are looking to do another Drupal build along the way. A/B testing is always in our toolbox and we'll need to find a good module now that website optimizer is rather less useful then it once was.

Comment: It was a poorly formatted link. This is what you're looking for: http://drupal.org/project/multivariate